# How do I solve this tricky logarithmic formula

Tags: logarithms

I have a formula as follows:

> $0.55508389365 = \ln(20 + x)/\ln(240 +x)$

I happen to know that x = 1 (approximately) is the solution.  But I'm not sure how I would go about solving this if I didn't know the answer.

By messing around with log manipulation I eventually got to

> $240 + x = (20 + x)$ to the power of $1/0.55508389365$

But I'm not sure how you would solve this either!

Is it possible to solve an equation like this?  If so how do I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where did that ugly decimal number $0.55508389365$ come from?

Comment: If I work the equation the other way.  So ln(21)/ln(241)

Comment: Apply Bisection method. You will get a pretty close answer I think

Comment: You might try rewriting $\ln(20+x)=\ln(20)+\ln\left(1+\left(\frac{x}{20}\right)\right)$ and doing the same for $\ln(240+x)$ and use the second or third degree Taylor approximation. For example $\ln\left(1+\left(\frac{x}{20}\right)\right)\approx \left(\frac{x}{20}\right)-\left(\frac{x}{20}\right)^2$. Second order would give a quadratic in $x$ which might give an approximate solution for $x$. Or you could go the cubic approximation which would be much messier.

Comment: p.s. My TI 84 gives the intersection of the two curves $(1, 0.55508389)$. Not everything must have an analytical solution.